# Email database URI

Tags: android, email

i have to access the email database schema like "mms-sms.db" can we able to access the database i am unable to find the database can anyone tell the exact **URI** of Default **Email** Program **Database**

Waiting for your **Authentic** answer is Required.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

First, there is no `mms-sms.db` in the Android SDK.

Second, there is no content provider for SMS in the Android SDK.

Third, there are many, many email clients for Android, including two that ship with the Android open source project, others created by device manufacturers, and third-party ones downloaded by users.

Fourth, none of those are part of the Android SDK, and I am not aware of any that have a documented content provider API (though some of the third-party ones might).

Hence, you cannot do what you want from the Android SDK. If you wish to integrate with third-party email clients (e.g., K-9), you can ask them how best to do that. There are no supported integration points with Email, Gmail, or the device manufacturer email clients.

Answer (score 0):

i used the following cursor, which brings all the emails but cant confirm whether this is a correct method... it worked for me...

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

This will return all details related to emails... just sort the details according to ur wish... hope this'll be helpful to u....

Comment: This returns email addresses, not emails.

Comment: Thanx Mark for correcting me on that... actually i kind of misunderstood the question itself!

Comment: Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI, null, null, null, null);

ContactMethods.CONTENT_EMAIL_URI
This email Uri is used to get the email id's of the Contacts that is store on your phone Contact 
i am asking about the email Content Email body, email Attachments, to and from Address

Thanks
Syed Asad Ali